# How to isolate Virtual Machine from Host OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I am not sure whether my Questions was right way of asking what i want, but what i want is that.

I want to use Vitrual Machine OS as main OS. Now when VM OS is open then there is a top bar  which belongs to vmware workstation from where i can minimise the VM and my HOst OS opens.
Is there any way where i can hide that bar so that if some uses that VM then they can't get into my HOST OS. ALso the pressing ALt CTrl Delete also opens for HOST OS as well.

```
HOST OS window 2008 server
VM OS 2008 server
Vmware Workstation
```

Comment: sounds like you want a "kiosk VM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with VMWare Workstation. If you want to put your production OS inside of a VM i would highly recommend using one of the free bare metal hyper-visors (ESXi or Hyper-V). This will allow you to allocate your resources on the server to maximum efficiency. My personal preference is ESX for this job.

Additionally, anyone who has console access to your server can compromise your server no matter what restrictions you put into place. If you really don't want them getting into your console session, leave it locked/logged out and when people need access they can RDP into the server you want them to access.

The reason that CTL+ALT+DEL brings up your OS is that it is intercepted by the host OS first, which brings up the security menu. Anything you do to get around this would be an ugly ugly hack.

Comment: I tried ESXi server. I installed that on machine but then i could not found the option to create VM in ESXi server interface. I have only one server computer where i want to install VM

Comment: Ditto - go with ESXi. One installed, all vm creation, modification, and console access is done through the vSphere client. If you have several VMs created, you can create different user accounts in vSphere, each of which can have access to a different set of servers. Then for any clients that need access to the servers, you either let them access via RDP or you create a vSphere account for them and let them use the vSphere client.

Comment: But where should i install vSpehere. I have only one computer at home and i want to install VMs in there. You mean to say that i need one more computer to install vSphere

Comment: If you only have one machine, ESXi is not going to work for you. ESXi is a bare metal hypervisor, you can't install it and then access the VM's at the local console, you have to access it from another machine, which you don't have.